# Sub-query not retrieving desired result

Tags: sqlite

So I need to eventually calculate the win/loss percentage of plaintiff lawyers in a database

The winner column has 3 possibilities plaintiff, defendant, blank

So I've been trying to do sub-queries, without success

```
SELECT plaintiffattorney, state_name, court_name, COUNT(plaintiffattorney) AS "Times Won", 
    (SELECT COUNT(plaintiffattorney) 
    FROM LawyerCase 
    WHERE winner is "Defendant" and filedate >= date('now', '-3 years')) AS "Times Lost"
FROM LawyerCases
WHERE winner is "Plaintiff" and filedate >= date('now', '-3 years') and plaintiffattorney IS NOT ''
GROUP BY plaintiffattorney
ORDER BY COUNT(plaintiffattorney) DESC;
```

The result of this query is:
[image: query1]

Every plaintiff shouldn't have the same number of times lost (801) and some might not have any losses within my specified time period

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subquery counts all rows in the table.

You have to restrict it to the rows belonging to the same attorney by [correlating](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#cosub) it with the outer table:

```
SELECT ...,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM LawyerCase AS LC2
        WHERE L2.plaintiffattorney = LawyerCase.plaintiffattorney
          AND ...
       ) AS "Times Lost"
FROM LawyerCase
...
```